# Interview about malloc in function

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory-leaks, malloc

I faced a question in an interview of a company, and I cannot figure out the reason about the answer.

```
void newArray(int* local, int size) 
{
     local = (int*) malloc( size * sizeof(int) );
}
int main() {
     int* ptr;
     newArray(ptr, 10);
}
```

Ans: This would cause memory leak and the program is not correct.

Does anyone know why this code cannot work?

Comment: Even if C wasn't passing the data by value, there's no call to `free` in this code, so it's gonna leak memory anyway.

Comment: @user2933783  I hope you passed the interview successfully. Otherwise it is entirely unclear why they spent their own time inviting you to interview and why they asked such questions.:)

Comment: I think your problem is with `pass by value` and `pass by pointer`.

Comment: @user2933783   By the way their qualification as C programmers is not very high. At least they even do not know how main without parameters shall be declared.:) Also the second parameter should have type size_t instead of the type int.:)

Comment: You can use valgrind to check for any memory leaks in your C program.
Please search for appropriate links and documentation on how to use valgrind to detect memory leak.

Comment: May I inquire which company what that?

Answer (score 8):

In C, all function parameters are pass by value.  So when the local variable `local` is modified inside of `newArray`, the change is not visible outside of the function.  So the memory pointer is lost and you have a memory leak.

To fix the leak, the function should accept the *address* of a pointer (i.e. a pointer-to-pointer), then dereference that pointer so that `ptr` in `main` is updated.  You would then need to call `free` to free the memory.

```
void newArray(int **local, int size) 
{
     *local = malloc( size * sizeof(int) );
}
int main() {
     int* ptr;
     newArray(&ptr, 10);
     free(ptr);
}
```

Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: in IDEs like visual studio, we will face an error if we don't cast the return value of malloc.

Comment: @FatemehKarimi If you're compiling as C++, then yes you'll get an error.  But if your source files are .c files, then you should be compiling as C where you should not make such a cast.

Answer (score 3):

It cannot work since it changes the value of an argument inside a function, but since C is call by value that has *no* relation to the value of the variable that was used as that argument outside the function.

In other words, `&local` inside `newArray()` is not the same as `&ptr` in `main()`; they're *different variables* so changing one has no effect on the other.

Answer (score 3):

You lose the reference to the malloced memory.  This should be Ok.

```
void newArray(int** local, int size) 
{
     *local = (int*) malloc( size * sizeof(int) );
}
int main(c,v) char **v; {
    int* ptr;
    newArray(&ptr, 10);
    /* Do something with ptr? */
    free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: That still leaks memory — it's just from `main()` now rather than `newArray`.

Comment: hahaha, good point.  I assume his actual program does something with the newArray(...) and free's it when finished, but you're right for this silly example I should add a `free(ptr)` before exiting main(...)

Answer (score 3):

For starters this program

```
void newArray(int* local, int size) 
{
     local = (int*) malloc( size * sizeof(int) );
}
int main() {
     int* ptr;
     newArray(ptr, 10);
}
```

demonstrates that who asked the question in the interview is not strong himself as a C programmer.

First of all, according to the C Standard, function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Secondly there is not any reason to declare the second parameter of the function `newArray` as having the type `int` instead of the type `size_t` because the standard function `malloc` used in the function has a single parameter of the type `size_t`.

Otherwise the function should check that the argument passed to the function is not a negative value.

As for the question then function parameters are its local variables. They are initialized by the supplied arguments. You can imagine the function definition and its call the following way

```
newArray(ptr, 10);

// ...

void newArray( /* int* local, int size */ ) 
{
    int *local = ptr;
    int size = 10;

    local = (int*) malloc( size * sizeof(int) );
}
```

As you can see it is the parameter (that is a local variable) `local` that is changed inside the function. The argument itself stays unchanged. Only the value of the argument is used to initialize initially the parameter. After exiting the function its local variables (including its parameters) are not alive and destroyed.

So the function indeed has a memory leak.

You should pass the argument by reference if you want that its value was changed in the function. For example

```
void newArray( int **local, size_t size  ) 
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    *local = (int*) malloc( size * sizeof(int) );
}
```

And the function should be called like

```
newArray( &ptr, 10 );
```

However a question arises what to do with the value of the pointer `*local` before reassigning it. Whether there should be called the function `free` before the call of malloc or not.

So a more clear function definition can look like

```
int * newArray( size_t size ) 
{
    return malloc( size * sizeof( int ) );
}
```

In this case it is the client of the function who decides what he should do with his own pointer which he is going to reassign.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `ptr` is passed by value (like everything else in C). So, assigning the return value of `malloc` to `local` changes only *local* variable, not `ptr` in `main()`.

As a result, there's no way to access the pointer returned by `malloc()` once the function `newArray` returns. Hence, it results in a *memory leak*.

It's similiar to:

```
void func(int x)
{
    x = 42;
}

int main(void)
{
   int y = 0;
   func(y);
   /* 'y' remains 0 */
}
```